# List of structs in (Rust) Polars column

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Let's say I have a Polars column of type `list[list[str]]`:

```
Foos
---
list[list[str]]

[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
[["g", "h"], ["i", "j"], ["k", "l"]]
[["m", "n"], ["o", "p"], ["q", "r"]]
...
```

and a struct `Foo`:

```
struct Foo {
    f1: &str,
    f2: &str,
}
```

How can I obtain a Series `list[Foo]`?

```
Foos
---
list[Foo]

[Foo { f1: "a", f2: "b" }, Foo { f1: "c", f2: "d" }, Foo { f1: "e", f2: "f" }]
[Foo { f1: "g", f2: "h" }, Foo { f1: "i", f2: "j" }, Foo { f1: "k", f2: "l" }]
[Foo { f1: "m", f2: "n" }, Foo { f1: "o", f2: "p" }, Foo { f1: "q", f2: "r" }]
```

I've tried with:

- `ChunkedArray<ObjectType<T>>`
- `StructArray<Struct>` with fields defined as:

```
let fields = vec![
    polars::prelude::ArrowField::new("first_name", polars::prelude::ArrowDataType::Utf8, false),
    polars::prelude::ArrowField::new("last_name", polars::prelude::ArrowDataType::Utf8, false),
];
```

to no avail.
Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for a single row:

```
let foo = StructChunked::new("foo", 
    &[
        Series::new("f1", ["a", "c", "e"]),
        Series::new("f2", ["b", "d", "f"]),
    ]).unwrap();
```

```
foo
---
list[struct[2]]

[{"a","b"}, {"c","d"}, {"e","f"}]
```

Comment: Does Rust “see” the struct as type Foo? Or some polars version of a struct with fields f1 and f2?